# How to download large subsets of USDA NAIP imagery from Box.com?

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, download, naip

The US Department of Agriculture’s [Geospatial Data Gateway](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/) states, ‘As of April 21, 2017 the NAIP datasets are only available through the "NAIP Download" option on the home page and are no longer be available through the Gateway ordering process.’ NAIP (the National Agricultural Imagery Program) is a dataset of satellite imagery of the continental US, and the link they provide lands me on this [Box.com shared link](https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/naip).

Box.com limits downloads to 15 GB, so the only way I can download all of [2017 North Dakota data](https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/naip/folder/43484391906) is to manually download files one-by-one, or select a few of them that are hopefully less than 15 GB and download as several batches.

I’ve [asked on Box’s help forum](https://community.box.com/t5/Box-Developer-Forum/Download-all-contents-of-a-Shared-Link-exceeding-15-GB/td-p/51147) and thought to also ask the GIS gurus here: is there any way to automatically download this data, either through Box or some other way?

Non-solutions I've tried:

- WebDAV doesn't follow shared links that I save in my Box.com (I signed up as a free user).
- FTP is not available for free users.
- The [Box REST API](https://developer.box.com/reference#get-a-folders-items) doesn't recognize `folder_id`s that I get from the URL (i.e., at [the list of 2017 data](https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/naip/folder/43479630877), the folder for `nd` or North Dakota is [43484391906](https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/naip/folder/43484391906), but `43484391906` is not a valid `folder_id` according to the API).
- Disabling JavaScript gives a list of files and directories but no download link works (looks like Box.com is only usable by JavaScript-enabled clients).
- This makes me wonder if using the [Box CLI](https://developer.box.com/docs/box-cli) will also turn out to be a non-solution in getting this data automatically.

Is it possible that the data is not accessible through the REST API because it's hosted on an on-premise appliance? (The `nrcs.app` prefix in the URLs makes me think this.)

Comment: I download with no problems a few weeks ago...I had to download a few of them let it run itself..

Comment: @PROBERT I want to download all the files for a tri-state region and don't have an intern handy to click a download button a few hundred times 

Comment: @PROBERT I'd like to make a local copy of the most recent data for the entire continental US but as a start, all of Ohio, Florida, and California–Nevada. Hope I don't sound greedy…

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to order state-wide NAIP datasets directly from the [USDA FSA Aerial Photography field Office](https://www.fsa.usda.gov/programs-and-services/aerial-photography/imagery-programs/naip-imagery/ordering-naip-imagery/index).

FSA requires a [small fee](https://www.fsa.usda.gov/Internet/FSA_File/fsa0441a_10302007.pdf) (usually $150 to $175 per state for ~0.5TB), although this includes an external hard drive supplied by FSA. You can request either digital ortho quarter quad tiles (DOQQs) or compressed county mosaics (CCM).

Comment: Is this option valid for non-US companies and non-US citizens?

Comment: @dementiev I do not know, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a large amount of data, you can pay a single $250 fee and have the data loaded on an external drive that you provide. See the [DataGateway's FAQ #1](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/GDGHome_FAQ.aspx).

Comment: Email the contact listed in the FAQ. What can it hurt?

Comment: @PROBERT If I read the FAQ correctly, it's free for USDA folks, $250 for non-USDA government folks, and not available for non-government, but yeah, let me email them. Thanks for pointing this out Bjorn!

Comment: Ugh—their response: "Distribution of NAIP in bulk is strictly for NRCS personnel" (NRCS is USDA)… though apparently "FSA-APFO is the other option for bulk delivery" so I'll try there. @PROBERT